# Does facebook pass data differently/in a different way when you use the canvas url?

Tags: ajax, facebook, oauth

I have built an frontend-authorization for facebook. When I set redirect_uri back to the source-page, I recieve a token that I can use to make api-calls

However, when I redirect to my facebook-canvas page, it complains when I try to make the ajaxcall:

```
Uncaught Could not perform AJAX call because no valid tokens was found.
```

I use a general-purpose oauth-library called [jso](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso), I chececked out the facebook sdk, and it doesn't really serve my purposes.

Comment: canvas apps are inside an iframe. so just make your ajax call to your page itself and not to the canvas url.

Comment: If i make the ajax call to my page, i don't get the canvas url...

Comment: you dont need the canvas url :) see it so.. you are in a room in a house. you just want to grap something from a room, you dont need to go through the main entrance door of the house, you can just go to the room :-)

Comment: But I want the canvas url, the app is a page Tab. I made a php-script that takes the post and adds it to a javascript variable.

Comment: sorry, you dont understand what i say....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's posted to the iframe rather than "get":ed. You need to catch it serverside.